# Does $ \frac{\partial }{\partial x^l}|_p x^j =\frac{\partial x^j}{\partial x^l}|_p=\delta^j_l $ make sense in the general manifold case?

Tags: differential-geometry, manifolds, smooth-manifolds

If I have a manifold $M$ of $\dim M=m$ that has an atlas with one map $(M; \varphi)$. If we denote the components of $\varphi$  with $x^1,\dots, x^m$.

**Does the following operation make sense?**

$\frac{\partial}{\partial x^l}|_p$ is an element of $T_pM$
so it is aderivation that can act on smooth functions over the manifolds such as $x^l$

$  \frac{\partial }{\partial x^l}|_p x^j =\frac{\partial x^j}{\partial x^l}|_p=\delta^j_l $

Why or why not? Can I really see this a elementary derivation, or are there intermediate steps that justify this is true in the manifold case? I am a bit confused because $x^j$ is a function and a variable at the same time when I do that partial derivative and I am working as if M was $R^m$

Answer (score 2):

Let $f :M \to \mathbb{R}$ a smooth function. If we denote the components of $\mathbb{R}^m$ with $r^1 \dots r^m$, by definition
$$
\frac{\partial}{\partial x^j}\Bigg|_p(f) = \frac{\partial}{\partial r^j}\Bigg|_{\varphi(p)}(f \circ \varphi^{-1})
$$
where the RHS is a derivation with respect to Euclidean coordinates. So in your case you can compute
$$
\frac{\partial}{\partial x^j}\Bigg|_p(x^i) = \frac{\partial}{\partial r^j}\Bigg|_{\varphi(p)}(x^i \circ \varphi^{-1} ) =  \frac{\partial}{\partial r^j}\Bigg|_{\varphi(p)}(r^i \circ \varphi \circ \varphi^{-1} ) = \frac{\partial r^i}{\partial r^j}\Bigg|_{\varphi(p)} = \delta^i_j.
$$

This reflects that manifolds are modeled as spaces which behave locally as the Euclidean space (at least when you make first order computations).

Comment: I thought the components of  $\Bbb R^m$ had to be denoted with the same symbol as the components of the chart map $\phi$, so both with $x^i$

Comment: In practice you often see this notation, however, if you want to define the coordinates on a manifolds, or the derivations along them, you need to make a clear distinction. On $\mathbb{R}^n$ with the identity as chart of course both notations coincide as $x^j = r^j \circ id$

Answer (score 1):

It makes sense. Have a look at
https://www.physicsforums.com/insights/pantheon-derivatives-part-iv/#B-%E2%80%93-Left-Invariant-Vector-Fields-and-GL-n
where the Lie groups $GL(n)$ and $SL(n)$ are the manifolds, and their tangent spaces at the identity matrix are computed. The calculation makes particular use of the equation, i.e. fact, you asked about.

The basic perspective is to consider a path $\gamma(t) $ through $p$ with $\gamma(0)=p$ and differentiate the function $f$ by $\left. \dfrac{d}{dt}\right|_{t=0}f(\gamma(t)).$ In the special case of your question, we have  $f=x^j$ and $\gamma=x^l$.

Comment: Did you mean $x^l$ ?The path $\gamma : I \subseteq \Bbb R \to M$  while $x$ being a component of the chart is $M \to \Bbb R$, so they can't be equal, can they?

Comment: I chose a simple case of an embedded manifold where the chart coordinates are simply the usual Cartesian coordinates and a path is a map $\mathbb{R}\rightarrow M \subseteq  \mathbb{R}^m$ with $m=n^2$ in my quoted link, or $m=n$ in your example. I would have written both indices as $x_j\, , \,x_l$ since that's what they mathematically are. I only wrote $x^j$ not to confuse you. Unfortunately, I have forgotten to do the same for $x^l.$ Corrected now.

Comment: The equation I am having trouble with is $\gamma=x^l$. It does not seem correct  because the domain of $\gamma$ is $\Bbb R$ while the domain of $x^l$ as coordinate function is $M$.

Comment: I think you should take a closer look at the example in my link. There we have Cartesian coordinates $x_{ij}$ of a curved manifold $GL(n)\subseteq \mathbb{R}^{n^2}.$ The point $p=1$ is the identity matrix.

Answer (score 0):

The trick to learning this is to observe that if $\phi: U \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^n$ is a coordinate map, then we can write $$\phi=(\phi^1, \dots, \phi^n)$$ and observe that $\phi^i$ is equal to as $x^i$ viewed as a function.

For simplicity, let's do this for $\dim M = 2$. Given a point $p \in M$, let $\phi: U \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^2$ be a coordinate map such that $p \in U$ and $\phi(p) = (0,0)$. Given a function $f: M \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$, the partial derivative of $f$ at $p$ with respect to $x^1$ at $p$, $$ \frac{\partial f}{\partial x^1} (p)$$ is defined to be $$ \left.\frac{d}{dt}\right|_{t=0}f(c(t)), $$ where $$c(t) = \phi^{-1}(t,0).$$ The partial derivative of $f$ with respect to $x^2$ at $p$ is defined similarly.
Therefore,
\begin{align*}
\frac{\partial x^1}{\partial x^1}(p)
&= \frac{\partial \phi^1}{\partial x^1}(p)\\
&= \left.\frac{d}{dt}\right|_{t=0}\phi^1(\phi^{-1}(t,0))\\
&= \left.\frac{d}{dt}\right|_{t=0}t\\
&= 1.
\end{align*}
The calculations for the other partial derivatives of $\phi^1$ and $\phi^2$ are similar and therefore
$$
\frac{\partial x^i}{\partial x^j}(p) = \delta^i_j.
$$
Since this equation holds for any $p \in U$, we get
$$
\frac{\partial x^i}{\partial x^j}(p) = \delta^i_j\text{, for all }p \in U. $$

Comment: Why is $ \frac{\partial f}{\partial x^1} (p)$  shorthand for $ \frac{d}{dt}f(c(t)), $ ? and why  is  $c(t) = \phi^{-1}(t,0)?$ The last expression is equivalent to $\phi(c(t))=(t,0)$ but still why?

Comment: I see that I didn't write this precisely enough. I'll edit it.